# left_join per group and add group value when missing

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering how to do a kind of left_join per group (which is not possible in dplyr for what I understand) and for which I would replace the missing value for the group value by the value of the group

Here is what I mean:
Starting from the following:

```
  ref  group value
    B group1     3
    C group1     4
    D group1     3
    A group2     6
    C group2     5
```

I woudl like to add to the missing letters to ref (from A to F) for each group
so it would be something like that:

```
  ref  group   vol
    A NA        NA
    B group1     3
    C group1     4
    D group1     3
    E NA        NA
    F NA        NA
    A group2     6
    B NA        NA 
    C group2     5
    D NA        NA
    E NA        NA
    F NA        NA
```

then replace (or at the same time) replace NA in group by the group value it belongs to..

```
  ref  group    vol
    A group1     NA
    B group1     3
    C group1     4
    D group1     3
    E group1     NA
    F group1     NA
    A group2     6
    B group2     NA 
    C group2     5
    D group2     NA
    E group2     NA
    F group2     NA
```

here is the initial data:

```
db <- structure(list(ref = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "C"), 
  group = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group2", "group2"), 
  vol = c(3, 4, 3, 6, 5)), class = "data.frame", 
  .Names = c("ref", "group", "vol"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

and the reference letters:

```
vars_to_add <- structure(list(ref = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")),
   class = "data.frame", .Names = "ref", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I could have a function filtering for each group and doing a left_join then replacing the value and then appending each group again into one data frame but maybe there is a smart way...
I could also define the groups in the vars_to_add but that's not viable for scaling up with more groups...

thanks

Comment: Please check the `dput` of 'db' it is not matching with the data you showed

Comment: @akrun changed it should be good, thks

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with the solution I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
complete(db, ref = vars_to_add$ref, group) %>%  
                 arrange(group)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   ref   group  value
#   <chr> <chr>  <int>
# 1 A     group1    NA
# 2 B     group1     3
# 3 C     group1     4
# 4 D     group1     3
# 5 E     group1    NA
# 6 F     group1    NA
# 7 A     group2     6
# 8 B     group2    NA
# 9 C     group2     5
#10 D     group2    NA
#11 E     group2    NA
#12 F     group2    NA
```

Comment: O_O amasing. ::thumb_up:: . I did see that function around during my search but didn't understand it obviously.